# Есть массив, надо его записать в файл каждый элемент массива через пробел

Tags: массивы, pascal

`s1` - string;
`arr` - массив

```
s1:=arr[i]+' '; 
write(f,s1);
```

Вот в чем проблема в конце строчки ставится пробел после последнего элемента. Как исправить?

Comment: язык на котором писал - pascal

Comment: например, сделать проверку в цикле - если не последний элемент -добавлять пробел .... или после цикла из строки удалить последний элемент... сделать `trim`

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый.

Answer (score 1):

Если индексы у массива начинаются от 1, то исправить это вот так:

```
s1 := '';
for i := 1 to arrLength - 1 do // добавим все, кроме последнего, ...
  s1 := s1 + arr[i] + ' ';          // ... с пробелом

s1 := s1 + arr[arrLength];  // добавим последний без пробела
write(f, s1); // запишем результат
```

Answer (score 0):

Внутри цикла делать проверку на то, последний это элемент или нет:

```
for i := 1 to arrLength do
  begin
    if i < arrLength then 
        s1:=arr[i] + ' ';  
    else
        s1:=arr[i];  
  end
```

Comment: Можно сократить... писать `s1:=arr[i]; ` в любом случае ...а ниже написать `if i < arrLength then    s1:= s1 + ' ';`

Comment: Старайтесь писать более детальные ответы. Можно объяснить путь решения, указать на конкретные ошибки, привести ссылки с более подробным разбором проблемы и т. п.

Comment: Проверка условия внутри цикла, которая сработает один раз в конце, это бесполезное замедление работы программы. Но если ваша цель нагреть помещение, где стоит комп, то это самое то, что нужно =)